# Create a sequential number (counter) for rows within each group of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How can we generate unique id numbers within each group of a dataframe? Here's some data grouped by "personid":

```
personid date measurement
1         x     23
1         x     32
2         y     21
3         x     23
3         z     23
3         y     23
```

I wish to add an id column with a unique value for each row within each subset defined by "personid", always starting with `1`. This is my desired output:

```
personid date measurement id
1         x     23         1
1         x     32         2
2         y     21         1
3         x     23         1
3         z     23         2
3         y     23         3
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 58):

Some `dplyr` alternatives, using convenience functions `row_number` and `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(personid) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
df %>% group_by(personid) %>% mutate(id = 1:n())
df %>% group_by(personid) %>% mutate(id = seq_len(n()))
df %>% group_by(personid) %>% mutate(id = seq_along(personid))
```

---

You may also use `getanID` from package `splitstackshape`. Note that the input dataset is returned as a `data.table`.

```
getanID(data = df, id.vars = "personid")
#    personid date measurement .id
# 1:        1    x          23   1
# 2:        1    x          32   2
# 3:        2    y          21   1
# 4:        3    x          23   1
# 5:        3    z          23   2
# 6:        3    y          23   3
```

Answer (score 32):

The misleadingly named `ave()` function, with argument `FUN=seq_along`,  will accomplish this nicely -- even if your `personid` column is not strictly ordered.

```
df <- read.table(text = "personid date measurement
1         x     23
1         x     32
2         y     21
3         x     23
3         z     23
3         y     23", header=TRUE)

## First with your data.frame
ave(df$personid, df$personid, FUN=seq_along)
# [1] 1 2 1 1 2 3

## Then with another, in which personid is *not* in order
df2 <- df[c(2:6, 1),]
ave(df2$personid, df2$personid, FUN=seq_along)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 19):

Using `data.table`, and assuming you wish to order by `date` within the `personid` subset

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Data)

DT[,id := order(date), by  = personid]

##    personid date measurement id
## 1:        1    x          23  1
## 2:        1    x          32  2
## 3:        2    y          21  1
## 4:        3    x          23  1
## 5:        3    z          23  3
## 6:        3    y          23  2
```

If you wish do not wish to order by `date`

```
DT[, id := 1:.N, by = personid]

##    personid date measurement id
## 1:        1    x          23  1
## 2:        1    x          32  2
## 3:        2    y          21  1
## 4:        3    x          23  1
## 5:        3    z          23  2
## 6:        3    y          23  3
```

Any of the following would also work

```
DT[, id := seq_along(measurement), by =  personid]
DT[, id := seq_along(date), by =  personid]
```

The equivalent commands using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
# ordering by date
ddply(Data, .(personid), mutate, id = order(date))
# in original order
ddply(Data, .(personid), mutate, id = seq_along(date))
ddply(Data, .(personid), mutate, id = seq_along(measurement))
```

Answer (score 7):

I think there's a canned command for this, but I can't remember it.  So here's one way:

```
> test <- sample(letters[1:3],10,replace=TRUE)
> cumsum(duplicated(test))
 [1] 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> cumsum(duplicated(test))+1
 [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

This works because `duplicated` returns a logical vector.  `cumsum` evalues numeric vectors, so the logical gets coerced to numeric.

You can store the result to your data.frame as a new column if you want:

```
dat$id <- cumsum(duplicated(test))+1
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your data are in a data.frame named `Data`, this will do the trick:

```
# ensure Data is in the correct order
Data <- Data[order(Data$personid),]
# tabulate() calculates the number of each personid
# sequence() creates a n-length vector for each element in the input,
# and concatenates the result
Data$id <- sequence(tabulate(Data$personid))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sqldf`

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="personid date measurement
1         x     23
1         x     32
2         y     21
3         x     23
3         z     23
3         y     23")

library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) count
       FROM df a, df b 
       WHERE a.personid = b.personid AND b.ROWID <= a.ROWID 
       GROUP BY a.ROWID"
)

#  personid date measurement count
#1        1    x          23     1
#2        1    x          32     2
#3        2    y          21     1
#4        3    x          23     1
#5        3    z          23     2
#6        3    y          23     3
```