# Numbering sub-categories of data

Tags: r

I have data which looks like this:

```
person_id   y_var   x_var
1           98      51
1           96      90
1           57      13
2           80      38
2           14      5
3           21      28
3           18      25
3           47      41
3           72      57
```

Can anyone tell me how to number each person's observations sequentially in the following way? In this simplified data set the `person_id` is a number but in my data it is an alphanumeric factor.

```
person_id   instance_id y_var   x_var
1           1           98      51
1           2           96      90
1           3           57      13
2           1           80      38
2           2           14      5
3           1           21      28
3           2           18      25
3           3           47      41
3           4           72      57
```

Thanks.

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); getanID(mydf, "person.id")` should do it....

Comment: Or `transform(dat, instanceid = ave(1:length(personid), personid, FUN = seq_along))`.

Comment: @David Arenburg I don't know if a 'more canonical' duplicate would be any of these: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996135/generate-id-for-each-subset-in-dataframe). They include quite a few alternatives, not the least `ave` / `seq_along`. Perhaps add an `getanID` alternative to them? Well, well, people keep answering the mega dupes anyway...

Comment: @Henrik OK, reopened, but I can't close it anymore. So please use your hammer on whatever dupe you feel is better before this question will receive yet another flood of answers.

Comment: Thanks folks. Sorry about that. I reworded my search loads of times but didn't find what I was looking for.