# Create group ID for runs of non-zero values

Tags: r, vector, grouping

I would like to find contiguous runs of non-zero elements in a vector (separated by at least one zero), and to assign an ID to each group (subsequent integer).

Toy vector:

`value <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3,   0, 0, 0,   1, 2, 3, 9, 8,   0, 0,   3, 2)`

In this example, there are three runs of non-zero values: [1,1,2,3,4,3], [1,2,3,9,8], [3,2], separated by chunks of one or more zeros.

Each non-zero run should have a unique ID: 1, 2, 3... Runs of zero should have `NA` as ID:

```
   value id
1      1  1
2      1  1
3      2  1
4      3  1
5      4  1
6      3  1
7      0 NA
8      0 NA
9      0 NA
10     1  2
11     2  2
12     3  2
13     9  2
14     8  2
15     0 NA
16     0 NA
17     3  3
18     2  3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `rle()`. First create a new vector replacing the zeros with NA.

```
x <- match(value != 0, TRUE)
with(rle(!is.na(x)), {
    lv <- lengths[values]
    replace(x, !is.na(x), rep(seq_along(lv), lv))
})
# [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA  3  3
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try:

```
as.integer(factor(cumsum(value==0)*NA^(value==0)))
#[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA  3  3
```

Comment: Good lord this is some wizardry

Comment: @RichScriven Lol :) Actually, in most cases `cumsum(value==0)` is just fine, but since OP seems to need zero values set to `NA` and the count progressive, a couple of tweaks were needed.

Comment: Use the attribute-dropping powers of `c()` to replace `as.integer()`.  Fore!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
id <- (value>0)^NA
x <- rle(value>0)$lengths[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
id[!is.na(id)] <- rep(seq_along(x), times=x)

#[1]  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
ifelse(value != 0, 
       cumsum(value != 0 & dplyr::lag(value) %in% c(0, NA)), 
       NA)

# [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA  3  3
```

Answer (score -2):

1. You need to define a vector of vectors so in v[0] you will find all values of the first group, and in v[1] you will find all values of the second group and so on,
2. You need to loop on all values when you find a zero value. Continue until you find anon zero. Increment the vector with one and add the value and so on,

I wish this answer be helpful.