# Numbering rows within group in a data frame when multiple variables grouped

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

Yes, there are several questions similar to this, but none of them involve multiple grouped variables, which causes the solutions for those questions to not work properly.  The best similar questions I can find are:

1. [Numbering rows within groups in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925063/numbering-rows-within-groups-in-a-data-frame), and
2. [Create a sequential number (counter) for rows within each group of a dataframe [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996135/create-a-sequential-number-counter-for-rows-within-each-group-of-a-dataframe)

Dummy data for my case:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
    s1 = c("111", "111", "111", "112", "112", "114", "114", "115"),
    s2 = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 3)),
    val = rnorm(8)
)
```

I want to provide a grouping ID for `s1` within group `s2`.  That is, I want it to reset each time `s2` changes.  Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  s1    s2        val    id
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 111   A     -0.465      1
2 111   A      0.871      1
3 111   A      0.823      1
4 112   A      0.561      2
5 112   A      0.197      2
6 114   B     -0.743      1
7 114   B      0.0847     1
8 115   B     -1.05       2
```

One of the suggested solutions for similar questions is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(s1) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
```

but that resets each time `s1` changes.  Similarly, these did not work either:

```
df %>% group_by(s1, s2) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
df %>% group_by(s2) %>% mutate(id = row_number())
df %>% group_by(s1) %>% mutate(id = row_number(s2))
df %>% group_by(s1) %>% mutate(id = cur_group_id())
df %>% group_by(s1, s2) %>% mutate(id = cur_group_id())
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(s2) %>% mutate(id = match(s1, unique(s1)))`

Comment: Thanks, that works. Never would have thought of this.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Why not post an answer? I suppose someone might be able to find a duplicate but I don't this this solution is obvious and deserves an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Two other potential solutions: `df %>% group_by(s2) %>% mutate(id = cumsum(s1 != lag(s1, default = first(s1))) + 1)` and `df %>% group_by(s2) %>% mutate(id = cumsum(!duplicated(s1)))`, although RitchieSacramento's answer is what I would use