# Adding a column indicating current count of non-missing rows for the same ID

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have a quick question about counting non-missing entries of a column. Let's say I have the data that looks like:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),var1=c(NA,2,5,3,NA,NA,6,4,4,NA,7))
```

How do I add a new column counting the current number non-missing var1 for each ID (as below)?

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),var1=c(NA,2,5,3,NA,NA,6,4,4,NA,7),count_nm=c(NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,1,1,2,NA,3))
```

The best I could do was to delete rows with var1==NA, and add the count for each ID. But I would like to know how to do it without deleting those rows. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996135/create-a-sequential-number-counter-for-rows-within-each-group-of-a-dataframe

Comment: I dont think it's an exact duplicate, @Friede - this add an additional complication of `NA` values. I cant seem to find an exact dupe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum`  on the `complete.cases`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data |> 
  mutate(count_nm = cumsum(complete.cases(var1)), .by = id)
```

I also like the convenient `collapse::fcumsum` function which has a `na.rm` argument.

```r
library(dplyr)
data |> 
 mutate(count_nm = collapse::fcumsum(var1 > 0, na.rm = TRUE), .by = id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
    var1 = c(NA, 2, 5, 3, NA, NA, 6, 4, 4, NA, 7),
    count_nm = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2, NA, 3)
  )

setDT(df)[!is.na(var1), count_nm_new := seq(.N), by = id] %>% 
  .[]
#>     id var1 count_nm count_nm_new
#>  1:  1   NA       NA           NA
#>  2:  1    2        1            1
#>  3:  1    5        2            2
#>  4:  1    3        3            3
#>  5:  2   NA       NA           NA
#>  6:  2   NA       NA           NA
#>  7:  2    6        1            1
#>  8:  3    4        1            1
#>  9:  3    4        2            2
#> 10:  3   NA       NA           NA
#> 11:  3    7        3            3
```

or

```
setDT(df)[!is.na(var1), count_nm_new := rowid(id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace` in `ave`.

##### base:

```
transform(data, na=ave(var1, id, FUN=\(x) replace(cumsum(!is.na(x)), is.na(x), NA)))
#    id var1 na
# 1   1   NA NA
# 2   1    2  1
# 3   1    5  2
# 4   1    3  3
# 5   2   NA NA
# 6   2   NA NA
# 7   2    6  1
# 8   3    4  1
# 9   3    4  2
# 10  3   NA NA
# 11  3    7  3
```

##### data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, na := ave(var1, id, FUN=\(x) replace(cumsum(!is.na(x)), is.na(x), NA))]
data
#     id var1 na
#  1:  1   NA NA
#  2:  1    2  1
#  3:  1    5  2
#  4:  1    3  3
#  5:  2   NA NA
#  6:  2   NA NA
#  7:  2    6  1
#  8:  3    4  1
#  9:  3    4  2
# 10:  3   NA NA
# 11:  3    7  3
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), var1 = c(NA, 
2, 5, 3, NA, NA, 6, 4, 4, NA, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```